# Practical applications of NIST new password policy

Tags: passwords, password-management, password-policy, nist

I have previously asked about the application of the NIST Special Publication 800-63-3 (password policy). [Password Policy](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/167635/password-policy)

Without a simple way to add a password blacklist to AD, what are the common strategies for implementing these recommendations ( https://pages.nist.gov/800-63-3/ ), in the real world? I am trying to rewrite the internal password policy but without this (what is seemingly an integral part) I'm not sure whether a hybrid policy would be better?

Comment: are you aware that MS released their own guidance document last year on this topic?

Comment: @schroeder I was not aware of that, just searched and found the recommendations. Without the adoption of a password list in AD, would you advise waiting until that comes into play before altering policy?

Comment: When and if you alter policy depends on your goals and what risks you want to mitigate. I'm not sure that I would hold off on implementing the correct alignment of risk treatments in policy just because one feature was not available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Other strategies would not only be difficult to implement, they might be  counter to the intent of NIST 800-63b. Fortunately, there are multiple blacklisting solutions, so **you probably don't need (or want) another strategy**.

Here's my reasoning.

First, to summarize from 800-63b, section 5.1, the portion about verifiers (such as passwords) that are directly applicable to checking the quality of the user's password.

Required:

- Authenticators (passwords) must be:

  - Minimum 8 characters
- Authenticators also checked against blacklist using "values known to be commonly-used, expected, or compromised" (the core of your question) - at least one of:

  - Passwords obtained from previous breach corpuses
  - Dictionary words
  - Repetitive or sequential characters (e.g. ‘aaaaaa’, ‘1234abcd’)
  - Context-specific words, such as the name of the service, the username, and derivatives thereof
- If found in blacklist:

  - advise the subscriber that they need to select a different secret
  - provide the reason for rejection
  - require the subscriber to choose a different value

By my reading, the intent of 800-63b section 5.1 appears to be:

- **Prevent users from using blacklisted passwords in the first place**
- **Train the user to understand why the password choices were poor**

If this isn't possible via the password-changing interface directly, other strategies would require imposition of those goals via human policy. This would require:

- *A separate way for users to look up passwords in the blacklist*. Since the Windows password-changing interface is dedicated and isolated by design, providing a digital way to do this would be tricky (and printing a book instead would be a usability and maintainability nightmare!)
- *A way to audit for compliance after the fact* (by cracking the passwords using the blacklist as a dictionary). You should be doing this anyway ... but in this case, I believe that it defeats the purpose of the NIST guidance (to ensure that the blacklisted passwords *are never used in the first place*)

Fortunately, you don't need another strategy, if you only need to do the following:

- Verify minimum length. The stock AD complexity requirements allow this already.
- Implement blacklisting. There are both commercial (Anixis, etc.) and FOSS (https://github.com/jephthai/OpenPasswordFilter) solutions.

In other words, **alternate strategies are not only not needed -- they would be impractical, provide a difficult user experience ... and may not actually be defensibly conformant**.